# Including Files from Different Directories

Tags: php, ajax, include, include-path, server-side-includes

So I have these files:

```
/
|
+ include/
|   |
|   + database.php
|
+ cart/
|   |
|   + table.php
|
+ cart.php
```

My cart.php displays the page with a table that was generated by table.php (included file). The reason that I have a separated file for the table is because I have to generate the table again after some operations in cart.php — the current table is removed and a new one is loaded with Ajax. However, my table.php file has this line:

```
require_once("include/database.php");
```

This is quite problematic, since when the file is included from cart.php, the path makes sense. But when it's called by itself, the current directory will be cart/ and there is no include directory in cart/.

Is there any way to fix this problem? I'd like to avoid using the big absolute path. Is it possible to tell PHP that include/ should be always searched for files, no matter where it was called? It it is, where should I do that (in which file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .htaccess, you can set include path **:**

**.htaccess:**

```
php_value include_path "/path/to/include/"
```

**php file:**

```
require_once get_include_path().'file.php';
```

Another way **:**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/include/database.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would suggest defining the (absolute) root path of your application in a constant, for example, add this to your config/bootstrap:

```
// Absolute path to your application's root directory
define('APP_ROOT', '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs');
```

Then you can just include using that constant, like:

```
require_once(APP_ROOT . '/include/database.php');
```

Comment: Ah, nice. Thanks for the constant tip, makes it much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

In table.php

```
require_once('../include/database.php');
```

Well, rereading your question, it looks like you want to `autoload` things, but we don't have enough information to determine if your classes are set up in a way conducive to autoloading.

Comment: Well, the problem with "../include/database/" is that then it wouldn't work when including from cart.php . Oh, and there are classes. I do prefer the procedural approach.